# How can I make vim to format matrix side by side

Tags: vim, formatting

I am using vim to log a lot of my day-to-day work. I usually have a lot of results with matrix. When I paste those at the end of the day I have pages of (sometimes) 0ne or 2 columns matrix

My question is how can I ask vim to programatically format
this:

```
R) DT = data.frame(x=rnorm(6),y=rnorm(6))
R) DT
           x       y
1 -0.0007499  0.7661
2  1.5559552 -0.6664
3  0.2082094 -0.1598
4 -0.1684766 -0.0536
5  3.1014233 -0.7439
6  0.1985104  2.0415
R) DT2 = data.frame(x=rnorm(7),y=rnorm(7))
R) DT2
          x       y
1 -0.005116 -0.4388
2  2.317381  0.6597
3  0.359883  0.4770
4 -1.426220  0.4911
5  0.468820 -0.3260
6  0.626147 -0.6254
7 -1.086660  2.1973
```

to this: side by side

```
R) DT = data.frame(x=rnorm(6),y=rnorm(6)) R) DT2 = data.frame(x=rnorm(7),y=rnorm(7))
R) DT                                     R) DT2
           x       y                                x       y
1 -0.0007499  0.7661                      1 -0.005116 -0.4388
2  1.5559552 -0.6664                      2  2.317381  0.6597
3  0.2082094 -0.1598                      3  0.359883  0.4770
4 -0.1684766 -0.0536                      4 -1.426220  0.4911
5  3.1014233 -0.7439                      5  0.468820 -0.3260
6  0.1985104  2.0415                      6  0.626147 -0.6254
                                          7 -1.086660  2.1973
```

---

EDIT:
Thanks everybody, Kent solution worked, strangely before `set ve=all` my `C-Q` did not allow to select a block like

```
############
###############
#########
#########
#########
```

I couldn't reach the last column of the second line (using `gvim` on `win XP`).

Now works very well
I'll also use `Ingo Karkat` plugin"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try following steps:

```
:set ve=all
```

move cursor to beginning of line `R) DT2 = data.frame(x=rnorm(7),y=rnorm(7))`

press `C-V`, then using motion magic to select the 2nd block

press `d`

move cursor to the first line, the position you want to paste the 2nd block. type `p`

if your text is always like that format, you could try this mapping:

```
:nnoremap <leader>mt :let &ve='all'<cr>gg/^R)<CR>n<c-v>G$dgg$3lp
```

then you could in normal mode type `<leader>mt` to do the transformation.

**NOTE**

- I have no experience of vim on windows... so you may have to change the mapping for windows blockwise selection. `<C-Q>` ? not sure.
- I assume the first line of the file is `R)...`
- this will paste the 2nd block to the position: 3 spaces after the end of 1st line, change the number 3 in mapping if you want to adjust it

[image]

Comment: Whoooo, thanks for that awesome answer!, unfortunately (see post bellow), the text might be with of different shapes

Comment: @statquant answer (mapping) updated for your "different shapes" requirement. see the animation.

Answer (score 1):

The key to this is *blockwise visual mode*. Go to the beginning of the second block (what should become the right column next to the first block), press <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd> (on Windows, this is often remapped to <kbd>Ctrl+Q</kbd>), create the selection with <kbd>$</kbd> and <kbd>j</kbd><kbd>j</kbd><kbd>j</kbd>. . ., then delete with `d`. Then go to the first line of the first block, <kbd>$</kbd> to go to the end of line, (optionally append padding whitespace), then paste with <kbd>p</kbd> . The second block should be pasted to the right of your cursor. Finally, you can delete the empty lines left where the second block was.

---

My [UnconditionalPaste plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3355) simplifies this task: You can then simply delete the second block with <kbd>dd</kbd> or <kbd>V</kbd><kbd>j</kbd><kbd>j</kbd><kbd>j</kbd>. . .<kbd>d</kbd>, and force a paste in blockwise mode with the plugin's <kbd>gdp</kbd> mapping.

---

If you find a way to determine the size of the blocks (the <kbd>}</kbd> key, which jumps to the next empty line, may come handy here), you can then put all of the steps into a custom mapping.

Comment: Sorry but I am a bit lost on the `jjj` part. I guess it is for delimiting the block but I can't find how to use it...

Comment: That `jjj...` is just the simplest (not best!) way to extend the selection to all lines by moving down.